# Is it ok to implement multi tenancy solely in a GenericRepository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Based on the ASP.net MVC tutorial's GenericRepository pattern ([Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)), what speaks against implementing multi tenancy as follows:

```
public class GenericMultiTenantRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : MultitenantEntity
{
    internal SchoolContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    ...
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        query = query.Where(entity => entity.TenantId == <TenantId>); /* Like this? */

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

and MultitenantEntity just being the following:

```
public class MultitenantEntity {
    public int TenantId {get;set;}
}
```

All entities now derive from MultitenantEntity and you can still program the entire app as if it was intended for just one tenant?

Am I overseeing something? Or is there a more widely accepted practice to achieve what I'm trying to do?

The same principles should be added to the insert method as well, but I omitted those changes for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I overseeing something?

No, that's basically it, if you want an entity to only ever be owned by one 'tenant'. I'm currently R&D'ing an even more generic framework that allows permissions to be assigned to each entity and repository, implementing CRUD and other permissions for single users and groups of users. I couldn't find any existing paid or free library to do this.

Keep in mind that when inserting or updating, you'll have to check for [overposting / mass assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) of related entities, where a malicious user can change the key fields (like ID) being posted.

If you don't, someone can call `Update(TEntity entity)` where `entity` is writable by the currently logged on user, but where `entity.RelatedEntity` actually belongs to someone else.

Of course in your case, you'd want to abstract merely the multi-tenancy-related code, so your `Get()` becomes:

```
public override virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    return base.Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties)
               .Where(entity => entity.TenantId == _tenantID);
}
```

Comment: Hi CodeCaster - I'm trying to implement something similar but I'm running into difficulties with virtual properties.  If you get a minute, would you mind taking a peek at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826316/virtual-navigation-properties-and-multi-tenancy