# Virtual Navigation Properties and Multi-Tenancy

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, multi-tenant

I have a standard `DbContext` with code like the following:

```
 public DbSet<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
 public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

I've recently implemented multi-tenancy by creating a `TenantContext` that contains the following:

```
  private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
  private readonly Tenant _tenant;

  public TenantContext(Tenant tenant)
        : base("name=DefaultConnection") {
        this._tenant = tenant;
        this._dbContext = new DbContext();
    }

   public IQueryable<User> Users { get { return FilterTenant(_dbContext.Users); } }
   public IQueryable<Interest> Interests { get { return FilterTenant(_dbContext.Interests); } }


   private IQueryable<T> FilterTenant<T>(IQueryable<T> values) where T : class, ITenantData
    {
        return values.Where(x => x.TenantId == _tenant.TenantId);
    }
```

So far, this has been working great.  Whenever any of my services creates a new TenantContext, all queries *directly off of that context* are filtered through this `FilterTenant` method that guarantees I'm only returning tenant-relevant entities.

The problem that I'm encountering is my usage of navigation properties that do not take this into account:

```
  using (var db = CreateContext())  // new TenantContext
        {
            return db.Users.
                Include(u => u.Interests).FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserId == userId);
        }
```

This query pulls up the tenant-specific `Users`, but then the `Include()` statement pulls in `Interests` for that user only - but across all tenants.  So if a user has Interests across multiple Tenants, I get all of the user's Interests with the above query.

My User model has the following:

```
 public int UserId { get; set; }
 public int TenantId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
```

Is there any way that I can somehow modify these navigation properties to perform tenant-specific queries?  Or should I go and tear out all navigation properties in favor of handwritten code?

The second option scares me because a lot of queries have nested Includes.  Any input here would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no other way than to either use reflection or query the properties by hand.

So in your `IQueryable<T> FilterTenant<T>(IQueryable<T> values)` method, you'll have to inspect your type `T` for properties that implement your `ITenantData` interface.

Then you're still not there, as the properties of your root entity (`User` in this case) may be entities themselves, or lists of entities (think `Invoice.InvoiceLines[].Item.Categories[]`).

For each of the properties you found by doing this, you'll have to write a `Where()` clause that [filters those properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-against-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string).

Or you can [hand-code it per property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228463/load-navigation-properties-with-filter-for-entity-framework-4-3).

These checks should at least happen when creating and editing entities. You'll want to check that navigation properties referenced by an ID property (e.g. `ContactModel.AddressID`) that get posted to your repository (for example from an MVC site) are accessible for the currently logged on tenant. This is your [mass assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) protection, which ensures a malicious user can't craft a request that would otherwise link an entity to which he has permissions (a `Contact` he is creating or editing) to one `Address` of another tenant, simply by posting a random or known `AddressID`.

If you trust this system, you only have to check the TenantID of the root entity when reading, because given the checks when creating and updating, all child entities are accessible for the tenant if the root entity is accessible.

Because of your description you *do* need to filter child entities. An example for hand-coding your example, using the technique explained found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079378/how-to-filter-nested-collection-entity-framework-objects):

```
public class UserRepository
{
    // ctor injects _dbContext and _tenantId

    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
    { 
        var user = _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.TenantId == _tenantId)
                                   .Select(u => new User
                                   {
                                       Interests = u.Interests.Where(u => 
                                                     u.TenantId == _tenantId),
                                       Other = u.Other,
                                   };                               
        }
    }
}
```

But as you see, you'll have to map every property of `User` like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  RE my statement - I meant that the User may have Interests across multiple Tenants.  Users are tenant specific with that query, but User.Interests is giving me tenant-agnostic Interests.  Thoughts?

Comment: In that case your choices are reflection or hand-coding. It depends a bit on the size of your project, but I'd start with hand-coding the specific queries in a `UserRepository` (and replace the `IQueryable<User>` in your context with that), and when you see certain patterns emerge, you can try to move towards reflection. It's not trivial.

Comment: Reflection seems expensive too, in terms of computation.  I'll do the hand-coded approach, and work my queries into a repository (as they probably should be anyways).  Thank you again!

Comment: You can of course always cache the looked up properties per type. Good luck anyway. :-)

Comment: I'm playing with this now - it seems like since I have to do manual queries and assign the User.Interests property, I have to replace all virtual collections with [NotMapped] non-virtual collections.  Does this sound right?  I feel so messy doing this...

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've just sent you an email :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to offer an alternative approach to implementing multi-tenancy, which is working really well in a current project, using EF5 and SQL 2012.  Basic design is (bear with me here...):

1. Every table in the database has a column (ClientSid binary, default constraint = SUSER_SID()) and is never queried directly, only ever via a dedicated view
2. Each view is a direct select over the table with `WHERE (ClientSid = SUSER_SID())` but doesn't select the ClientSid (effectively exposing the interface of the table)
3. EF5 model is mapped to the VIEW, not the TABLE
4. The connection string is varied based on the context of the tenant (user / client whatever multi-tenant partition requirement may be)

That's pretty much it - though it might be useful to share.  I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but this has resulted in basically zero custom code in the C# area.

Comment: interesting... I know next to nothing about SQL Views so I'll need to read up on that.  Would your approach change if Users could be part of multiple Tenants (shared profile like on SO, for example)?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but a 'tenant' in this approach is defined by the connection used to authenticate to the SQL database.  Say you wanted to get data from multiple tenants in a single query, then this approach probably isn't what you want.  The DbContext is guaranteed to only ever get data from a single 'tenant'.  You can switch 'tenant' by swapping out the connection string.  But be aware you have a different set of issues, such as managing the connection strings.  We have a separate 'standard' database for storing the tenant -> connection map (using hashed values)